# Cannot find WebElement (Selenium, Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I have to find an element on the page by XPath.
When i open the page directly (through chromeDriver.get("https://some source") - i can find all elements that i need.

But when i run auto-test and ask Selenium:

1. Open Browser (yandex.ru or any other)
2. Put keyWord on search field and click "Search"
3. Find header that has link to https://some source and click that
4. Find needed elements on page (on https://some source) 

   I face a problem: needed elements not found (you cannot find any element on this page).

*So, we have same web-page, we have same logic on that page (we are looking for webElements)*, **but result depends on way how we got on source**. If we go directly - everything is fine, if selenium find header and click that to get on the source - problem appears.

you can see video of problem:
[enter link description here](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/u9cexE_BIQQsMA)

Comment: Update the question with your text based code trials.

Comment: Load the content of the page into a string and see if the required element is there.

Comment: Either it could be one of the following, please try it out:
1. different window - window handling - switchTo()
2. iFrame
3. try javascript for locating the webelements